# Mapping arrays inside array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map all projects in one array:

```
[
  [
    { id: 0, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'},
    { id: 1, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.}
  ],[
    { id: 3, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'},
    { id: 4, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.}
  ]
]
```

All in one array (output):

```
[
 { id: 0, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'},
 { id: 1, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.},
 { id: 3, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'},
 { id: 4, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.}
]
```

I tried `var result = allUserProjects.map(user => {user.map(project => project)})`
but that changes nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  [
    { id: 0, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'},
    { id: 1, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'}
  ],[
    { id: 3, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'},
    { id: 4, name: 'New Project', apiKey: '.'}
  ]
];

const output = arr.flat();
console.log(output)
```

You can use `Array.flat()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat